# Running Wiremock standalone jar in MAC

Tags: macos, wiremock

I am trying to use wiremock standalone jar in Macbook Pro. I have java version 1.7. as below :

java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

I am getting below error, pls help me ow to resolve this.
When I run this in windows, it works fine. Do we have any restrictions in Mac.

Command used: java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.35.0.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/standalone/WireMockServerRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

```
Tried to set the path for the Java , still did not work.
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can tell you're trying to run a jar compiled against Java 8 with Java 7, that's not gonna work.

You need to download the correct version of Java and run it with it.

Edit:

According to their [site](https://wiremock.org/docs/download-and-installation/) you need to use this version : 2.27.2

That's their last compatible with Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use Mac OS on Macbook pro, there is ability to install it with brew command :

> brew install mockserver

2. Later there will be chance to run it a follows
   In this case I tried to catch traffic and re-route it to the server after logging. Anyway,

> mockserver -serverPort 7070 -proxyRemotePort 8118 -logLevel DEBUG
> -proxyRemoteHost 127.0.0.1 -jvmOptions $javaOps

According to you error:
It appears when you trying to run part of code compiled on higher version on lower JVM version.